# Ionic - Not receiving push notification on android 8.1.0 using urbanairship-cordova 7.2.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, urbanairship.com, android-8.1-oreo

We are trying to update urbanairship-cordova plugin to version 7.2.0 on Ionic Project. We've followed this step https://www.npmjs.com/package/urbanairship-cordova. We send sample notification using urbanairship dashboard but we cannot get the push notification. This is the error log we've got from android studio :

> E/UALib: JobDispatcher - UAirship not ready. Rescheduling job:
>   JobInfo{action=ACTION_UPDATE_PUSH_REGISTRATION, id=4, extras='{}',
>   airshipComponentName='com.urbanairship.push.PushManager',
>   isNetworkAccessRequired=true, initialDelay=0, persistent=false}

Can somebody help us to solve that error ?

Comment: Did you see any other error? You can confirm that the UAirship get the deviceID and you accept the push permissions?
Check that [pr 254](https://github.com/urbanairship/urbanairship-cordova/pull/254) could help.

Comment: I've already fixing this error by update the android platform to 6.3.0 and use the urbanairship-cordova version 6.9.2. Thank you for the advise @GuillemPerez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already fixing this error by update the android platform to 6.3.0 and use the urbanairship-cordova version 6.9.2.

Comment: The cordova plugin moved to FCM. It now requires a google-services.json file to be added to your project.